# ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER after adding ProgressBar into my layout

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions

After adding the ProgressBar to my layout, I getting rained by this error:

```
Attempt to update InputPolicyFlags without permission ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER
```

How I can fix it, since I can't add this permission into my project? I couldn't find much on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Low level access to Surface Flinger is granted only to components that a part of the system and not to applications developed using the SDK and signed using an arbitrary certificate.

Refer: [Question answered by Android Framework Engineer](https://groups.google.com/g/android-porting/c/aN6D_vL9xxE)

Comment: I'm wondering, what does a single view have to do with low level system stuff